# Choosing a font string for Emacs

Tags: emacs

I like this specific font for Emacs:

```
 -unknown-DejaVu LGC Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
```

I know I like it because I tested it using `M-x helm-select-xfont` using the Emacs [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki) extension (previously known as anything). This command shows a list of fonts available on my system, and it allows me to try them temporarily.

How do I make this font my default font in my Emacs init file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(set-default-font "FONT-NAME")
```

You replace FONT-NAME with `-unknown-DejaVu LGC Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier solution is to do so using the menu (while I am against using the menu, though if you don't want to get your hands dirty, try the following):

Menu: Options -> Set Default Font..., and then pick that font (you can also set it to be **bold** and what not).

Next, go back to Options and hit "Save Options". I believe this would save this for future sessions.